# Adding more than one Stack Exchange OpenID credential

Tags: support, login, stack-exchange-openid, auto-login

I'm trying to add multiple logins for my Stack Overflow account. In "My logins", I clicked "add more" and then when I click the "Stack Exchange" icon it's logging me into the existing account.

I'm not able to add another Stack Exchange login.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot be logged into two Stack Exchange OpenIDs at the same time. So, to make this work, you're going to need to add a third-party login first. Looking at the email address you have used to create your existing SE OpenID, I suggest adding a Google credential. :)

So, follow these steps:

1. Go to "my logins", click "add more logins" and pick a Google account of your choice.
2. Sign out of SE OpenID by going to https://openid.stackexchange.com/user and selecting "logout".
3. Go back to your Stack Overflow profile, sign in with the Google account you added in step one.
4. Go to "my logins", click "add more logins", and you should be able to add a new Stack Exchange OpenID from there.